# EF7 Navigation property not getting load when method is getting called from web API project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on a huge project, where there are list modules and for each modules there are list of class libraries and a web API project which calls all modules.
What I mean is my project structure looks something like this -

```
-WebAPI (WebAPI project, which has reference to all Modules class libs)
-AccountManagementModule (Folder)
--AccountManagement.Repository (Class Library)   
  -GetAllProfileAndAddress (Method name inside a class Profile)
--AccountManagement.Test (Another Class Library for xunit test)
```

Now when I am calling "GetAllProfileAndAddress" method from my "AccountManagement.Test" project, I am able to get profile and all address related to that profile, through the navigation property of EF7.

Here is my Method, which Gets the Profile information -

```
public Profile GetProfile(Guid profileID)
{
   var parent =  uow.Repository<Profile>().Get(c => c.ProfileID == profileID);
}
```

However, when i am calling the same method using my web API controller action method, navigation property is not getting load.

What I mean is, When I call method "GetAllProfileAndAddress" from my "AccountManagement.Test" project, I am getting below result

```
{
"Response": {
"Success": true
"Data": {
"ParentID": "18b96fa4-f6a5-4802-ba9e-bacba0b1500f"   
"LastAppUseDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
"Note": "This parent is associated with other students as well."
"ProfileID": "808b2d97-a5c6-4ef3-8899-9b0592ca3293"
"Address": <<Here I am getting the whole address object>>
}-
}-
}
```

However, When I am calling "GetAllProfileAndAddress" from my "WebAPI" project, I am getting NULL object for Address property -

```
 {
    "Response": {
    "Success": true
    "Data": {
    "ParentID": "18b96fa4-f6a5-4802-ba9e-bacba0b1500f"   
    "LastAppUseDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    "Note": "This parent is associated with other students as well."
    "ProfileID": "808b2d97-a5c6-4ef3-8899-9b0592ca3293"
    "Address": Null
    }-
    }-
    }
```

I am using Visual studio 2015, dnxcore50 and Entity Framwork 7 (7.0.0-rc1-final).

Can anybody tell me why navigation property is null only when being called from WebAPI project?

Comment: Can you show your Repository<T>().Get() method code please?

Comment: I guess that in your test project lazy loading occurs because the context is still alive. Or you've got different serializer settings.